# Redirecting CGI(perl) error output to client

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I use perl as cgi for apache server,when each time the script encounters an error,the client just show *500 error* and I have to check the *apache error log* every time.

Is there a way to let perl send it's error message just to the client (just like asp's debug mode)?

Comment: Are the errors ones you're generating, or something perl itself is generating?

Comment: You can of course do "tail -f /path/to/error_log" and keep that window open while you debug. But CGI::Carp is the right answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the CGI::Carp module:

```
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
```